How could mermaids tails be bendable like manatees?
I've been working on creating anatomically correct mermaids, and I've looked through all the posts about them on here. My question does not appear to have been asked. For reference, my mermaids are aquatic mammals, with vertical tails, covered with skin rather than scales, and no sharp differentiation between their upper and lower bodies. They roughly follow this diagram.

Two aquatic mammals--manatees and dugongs--have bendable tails. I have attached pictures to explain what I'm talking about.


Is it plausible for my mermaids to be able to bend in a similar way, so that they could "sit" in a sense, albeit not in the same way as humans? What would I need to change about their physiology to make this work? Could I make them even more bendable than manatees?

If you want to go for a manatee-like capability of bending and sitting, you should probably go for a manatee-like skeletal anatomy, which is not far from what you have shown: just remove the human-like pelvic bone (Image source: broward.org).

As you can see the pelvic bone in manatee is almost atrophic, which gives the tail the additional freedom to bend.
Also note that in general marine mammals do not have pelvic or anal fins like in the drawing you have used, and that's consistent with the atrophy of pelvic bone and hinder legs.

Oh thanks! Yeah that makes sense, there'd be no point of a pelvic bone when you have a tail.

Like this? https://i.postimg.cc/hPgWVH27/temp.png

But if they don't have a pelvic bone, why would they have a waistline (or a butt)? Shouldn't they have an amorphous, manatee-like body shape then?

I don't know, that's a good question. I want my mermaids to appear humanoid and be descended from a common ancestor, so maybe they could retain the pelvic bone but a smaller version of it.

Even if you don't want to eliminate the pelvic bones as suggested by LDutch, the flexibility of the spine - or the tail - depends upon how the vertebrae are articulated.  In an aquatic environment, having thicker cartilaginous disks between the vertebrae will lead to increased flexibility, and the lack of need to constantly support weight on land will provide a reduced evolutionary counter-pressure.
